# How to improve search functionality in java?

Tags: java, android, html, database, search

I made a simple  search function  that  finds string inside a large number of html files (+8000) 
this is my code :

```
public Boolean loadAssetTextAsString(Context context, String search,String name) {
    Boolean exist=false;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String str;
        boolean isFirst = true;
        while ( (str = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            if (isFirst)
                isFirst = false;
            else

            if (str.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(search)){

                Log.e(" SUCC",str);
                exist=true;
                break;
            } else {                    Log.e(" Fail",":(");
            }
        }
        return exist;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return exist ;
}
```

**Problems:**
the problem is that this method is extremly slow and not useful at all .
is there a way or algorithm  to search inside a large number of files in a short time ?

Comment: Instead of a linear search you want an inverted index (like the one in the back of a book). You probably don't want to implement this yourself, this is what Lucene (a Java search library) was made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of things i can recommend;

First of all if searched string is too big than java's native contains function may be slow since that is not what it is designed for. Native contains function delegates its operation to indexOf function and it is not particularly fast for big data. Depending on your hardware/time requirements you can look for a more efficient String search library. Here's a library i use and it is okay http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/. It's usage is very easy and its performance is quite good. But I am sure there are better alternatives.

Also you can use redix trie or suffix tree these are far better suited for this kind of operations and much faster but they require a pre-processing of the data and might require more processing power.

You didn't state that if you use threading or not but from what i understand this search operation can be done concurrently. Even if you use two threads you can reduce the time to half, providing read operation is not bottleneck.

For optimizing reading operation you can do a couple of things. You can use new java.nio package which offers some nifty tricks. java.io package read functions read the file completely to memory which can exhaust the memory pretty quickly if your files are large. But with java.nio package you can do this operation more efficiently.

Moreover you can do reading operation while previously read Strings are being search and cache the results to use them.

You can also integrate apache lucene into your code however its learning curve is somewhat steep but this kind of search operations are why apache lucene is build for.

Comment: Thanks a LOT  for your  well written  answer  :)  .I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is called "full text index".
You might have a look at Lucene (or SOLR that resides above it). 
I also hear some databases have similar functionality (e.g. oracle) but I'm not sure how mature it is.

Basically, the idea on a full text index is pre-preparation. Breaking each document into words (and Lucene has some configurable Analyzers for it, it's not a trivial task), then the indexing tool creates an index that, for each word, says which pages contain it. Roughly speaking :

```
Given the documents:
doc #1:  "I like cakes"
doc #2:  "My cake recipe"

You'll have an index:
"cake" -> pages 1, 2
"like"-> page 1
"recipe" -> page 2
...
```